# Zend Framework 2 returning object as a query result

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a query in ZF2 like following:

```
public function BrandWallBrandsById($userId,$brandId,$startDate,$endDate)
    {
            $select = new Select();
            $select->from(array('p' => $this->table), array('id'));
            $select->join(array('b' => 'brands'), 'p.brandId = b.id', array('id','name', 'cover', 'slogan', 'startDate', 'homepage'));
            $select->columns(array(new Expression('SUM(p.points) as points'), "userId", "brandId"));
            $select->order("p.points desc");
            $select->group("p.brandId");
            $where = new Where();
            $where->notEqualTo("p.points", 0);
            $where->equalTo("p.userId", $userId);
            $where->equalTo("p.brandId", $brandId);
            $where->between("p.time", $startDate, $endDate);
            $select->where($where);
            return $this->historyTable->selectWith($select)->toArray();

    }
```

Since I'm returning only a single object, can I return an object from this query instead of an array[0] ??  Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Which is the type of the attribute **historyTable** of your class?

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting a signle row from your query then you can use [`current()`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html#basic-usage). Modify the last line of your code, juste like this:

```
$row = $this->historyTable->selectWith($select)->current();
if(!$row){
    throw new Exception('No row found');
}
return $row;
```